# Implementing authentication with passport / node.js and getting error

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I had already implemented authentication for the app I'm working on but am trying to refactor it based on a recent tutorial I did which I thought was very clear and also involved adding facebook / google / twitter auth which I would like to do.

So far, I've updated the user model and defined my local strategy for signup but when I go to try and run the app now, I'm getting an error. I have the app uploaded to github and wondered if somebody would be able to check it out and see where I'm going wrong. The error is pointing to a part of the index file until node_modules / express but I cannot work out what's up and I'd like to know before I proceed further.

Latest commit is under: https://github.com/DaveBage83/friendly-invention
Thanks!

Comment: Please don't post links to external code. Extract what is causing the issue, include it in the post here. Links frequently die. What if someone finds the thread in 3 months time and the latest commit is completely different?

Comment: understand. Problem here is I really have no idea what part of the code is causing the issue!

Answer (score 0):

A few things for you notice.

1 - Do not commit the *node_modules* folder. Once you have all your dependencies in the *package.json* file, the *npm install* will download all of for you again.

2 - This code is full of erros. I won't put everything here, I believe you find them by yourself. Otherwise, put the specific code here, so we can help you out.

About the question:

In you *app.js* file.

```
...
authRoutes = require('./routes/index')(app, passport)
...
```

If you look at the ./routes/index, you'll see that it is exporting a *route* object, witch does not expect the two parameters. (e.g. (app, passport)).

Hope it can still help you.